# Why is the IntelliJ IDEA Plugin Option gone in the Create new Xtext Project Advanced Configuration?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I'm using the 2021 versions of eclipse, Xtext and Xtend and I'm trying to create a Xtext project that can create a plugin for IntelliJ.

I'm using the "Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend - Second Edition" as a tutorial and followed the instructions there, however I'm stuck in chapter 11, where I'm supposed to click the option "IntelliJ IDEA Plugin" that I can also see in other screenshots, but my eclipse doesn't have it.

[Here is how it looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46TO3.png) [and here is how it is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRrsF.png)

Do recreate: New..Xtext Project -> Next -> There should be a IntelliJ IDEA Plugin Checkbox but there isn't

I tried googling it but everything I found had the option and I couldn't find anyone else with the same problem. I suspect it has something to do with the loosing support of Xtend but I can't find anything that could confirm that.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ support was dropped long time ago

https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-idea

You might have more luck when generating a Language server and try run it under IntelliJ